# Change checkout page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have a developed an e-commerce website with WordPress and WooCommerce plugin. Everything has been done but I want to change the complete layout of the checkout page. I tried finding a plugin to do that but failed.

Is there any way by which I can change the layout or the design of the checkout page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED: 


THE WOOCOMMERCE TEMPLATES:**

You can copy the "**templates**" folder (located inside the woocoommerce plugin folder) to your theme (or child theme) folder and rename it "**woocommerce**". 
Then you can chose inside which file you want to edit to feet your needs.

In your case you will find inside a folder named "**checkout**". All the files inside this "checkout" folder are the different components of the checkout page layout.

> **Different files responsible for components on checkout page/form**
>
> `form-checkout.php` is the primary file called for checkout page.
>   `form-login.php` renders the login form.
>   `form-coupon.php` renders the coupon form.
>   `form-billing.php` renders the billing form.
>   `form-shipping.php` renders the shipping form. (this is displayed when "ship to different address checkbox is checked)
>   `review-order.php` renders the order review block.
>   `payment.php` renders payment options block.
>   `payment.php` has a loop in which for each enabled payment method another file > `payment-method.php` is called.
>   `cart-errors.php` displays cart error.
>   `thankyou.php` is called for displaying order received confirmation. ("order-received" endpoint)

**ADDING WOOCOMMERCE STYLE SHEET IN CHILD THEME FOR EASY MODIFICATION**
Because some times is very difficult to overrides some specific WooCommerce styles.

**Step.1** - Disable the general woocommerce.css file.

Add this PHP code to your active theme's functions file (`functions.php`):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', 'wooc_dequeue_styles' );

function wooc_dequeue_styles( $enqueue_styles ) {
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-general'] );
    return $enqueue_styles;
}
```

**Step.2** - Create a new folder inside your active theme's folder named "woocommerce" *(if it doesn't exist yet)*.

**Step.3** - Copy the **woocommerce.css** file into this newly created folder **woocommerce** in your active theme's folder.
The **woocommerce.css** file is located in: plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css.

**Step.4** - Enable (enqueue) the general woocommerce.css file in your active theme.

Add this PHP code to your active theme's functions file:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woocommerce_style_sheet');

function woocommerce_style_sheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'woocommerce', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/woocommerce/woocommerce.css' );
}
```

***Options:***

— You can also enable/disable others woocommerce css files: [see this snippet at woo themes](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/)

— You can disable ALL Woocommerce style sheets at once:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: no the `checkout` page doesn't seem to available in template folder actually. the modify `checkout`page in woocommerce a little bit different with other pages

Comment: @Radian Inside templates folder, you have a complete subfolder named "checkout" with different components of the checkout page: [Woocommerce location of checkout template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774779/woocommerce-location-of-checkout-template). I have myself personalized checkout pages on some web-shops. You can also [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/).

Comment: What "Loic TheAztec" has mentioned is correct. The "checkout" folder within woocommerce templates is responsible for the checkout page layout. Though changing the layout of checkout page is bit difficult as compared to other template pages, its not absolutely impossible. I also have customized the checkout page layout as per the provided design.
@Loic TheAztec removing woocommerce default styles is not necessary. Rather it provides base layout upon which custom design can be build by overriding available selectors/classes.

Comment: @zipkundan I have **updated my answer**. Sometimes you need to disable the general woocommerce.css file because is not possible to override some styles (when the woocommerce.css files are loaded after your theme css rules. So you unset from woocommerce to set it in your theme folder, **FOR EASY MODIFICATIONS**. It's also useful if you make a bunch of changes.

Comment: @Loic TheAztec: True, what you say about css loading sequence. That might happen some times. I would suggest a small edit in the sequence of the steps you have mentioned. Enqueuing woo's styles via applied theme should immediately follow the disabling step. That will help the new learners understand the concept.